# PayPal Checkout JS Error Handling

Tags: javascript, paypal

I was reading this little section of the PayPal Checkout docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/how-to/customize-flow/#manage-funding-source-failure. Here they include this code snippet:

```
paypal.Button.render({
  //Configure environment
  env: 'production', // To test, set to `sandbox`
  payment: function () {
    // Set up the payment here, when the buyer clicks on the button
  },
  onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
    // Call your server to execute the payment
    if (error === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
      actions.restart();
    }
  }
}, '#paypal-button');
```

Does anyone know if that documentation is correct? Does the PayPal checkout.js manage an error variable in the global scope? If not, how do you correctly implement this guidance?

Note: cross-posted https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/790

Answer (score 0):

That documentation isn't correct. The checkout.js code handles one /payment error for you - INSTRUMENT_DECLINED - by automatically restarting the transaction, which you could do yourself with a call to "actions.restart()".

All other error messages, including HTTP errors, go to an error message handler that you need to set up. For example:

```
paypal.Button.render({
env: 'sandbox',
payment: function () {
  // Set up the payment here, when the buyer clicks on the button
},
onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
  // Execute the payment here, when the buyer approves the transaction
},
onError: function (err) {
  // Show an error page here, when an error occurs
}
}, '#paypal-button');
```

Note that if you are doing a Server Integration, then the server would handle errors, not the button.